# Suppose a vector $x$ is orthogonal to both vectors $y$ and $z$. Prove that $x$ is orthogonal to any vector in $\operatorname{span}\{y, z\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Sorry, I don't have any ideas on how to start this one.

Is it because of some relation between $y$ and $z$?

Comment: What does an arbitrary element in $\text{span}\{y,z\}$ look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are orthogonal if and only if $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = 0$. Since $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal to both we know that $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = 0$ and $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{z} = 0$. The span of $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$ are all possible linear combinations of the two. So if a vector $\vec{m}$ is in the span, then $\vec{m} = a\vec{y} + b\vec{z}$ for some scalar values $a$ and $b$. The dot product of $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{x}$ is
\begin{align}
\vec{x} \cdot \vec{m} &= \vec{x} \cdot (a\vec{y} + b\vec{z})\\
&= a(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}) + b(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{z})\\
&= a(0) + b(0) = 0
\end{align} 
Since the dot product of $\vec{m}$ and $\vec{x}$ is zero it follows that the two vectors must be orthogonal. And since $\vec{m}$ can represent any vector in the span, if follows that $\vec{x}$ is orthogonal with any vector in the span.

Comment: Oops, I should have gotten this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any $u\in{\rm span}\{y,z\}$, which can be expressed as $u=ky+lz$ for some scalars $k,l$, we can see that 
$$x\bullet u=x\bullet(ky+lz)=kx\bullet y+lx\bullet z=0,$$ 
since both $x\bullet y$ and $x\bullet z$ are zero.